# How to get a feedback statistic using civicrm custom field?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, reports, searchkit, feedback

I have created a set of custom fields with 5 questions. It has 5 radio button rating 1 to 5.
Then the questions were used in a profile to receive feedback from customers for the services they are receiving.

I am struggling to get a meaningful report/statistics for all the questions individually or collectively. I have tried searchkit but cant get the count of total of each question.

Has anyone tried this before? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SUM function in fields to get the total number per record, but you will need to group by record id

Comment: Thanks, full_group_by needed to be turned off from mySQL as well.